# MySQL multi table join

Tags: mysql

I have data coming from 3 different tables and i need to do some conditional select between them. DB query is as follows:

```
    SELECT proddb.onrrnr, 
       proddb.onr                 AS tellimus, 
       proddb.idnr                AS ID, 
       proddb.prod                AS toode, 
       proddb.proddate, 
       CASE 
         WHEN pf_prodQtySeq.glLiteNr = 1 THEN pf_ordRowSeq.gl1 
         WHEN pf_prodQtySeq.glLiteNr = 2 THEN pf_ordRowSeq.gl2 
         WHEN pf_prodQtySeq.glLiteNr = 3 THEN pf_ordRowSeq.gl3 
         WHEN pf_prodQtySeq.glLiteNr = 4 THEN pf_ordRowSeq.gl4 
       END                        AS klaas, 
       Sum(pf_prodQtySeq.planQty) AS kogus      
FROM   proddb 
      JOIN pf_prodQtySeq 
         ON proddb.onrrnr = pf_prodQtySeq.onrrnr 
      JOIN pf_ordRowSeq 
         ON proddb.onrrnr = pf_ordRowSeq.onrrnr
WHERE  pf_prodQtySeq.prLineSh = 'HEG' 
       AND pf_prodQtySeq.planQty > 0 
GROUP  BY proddb.idnr 
ORDER BY klaas DESC LIMIT 1000,25;
```

EDIT: in  code there where also ORDER and LIMIT clauses, LIMIT is this which turns query execution speed down to ˇ10 secs, without LIMIT query takes about less than 1 sec. How to optimize LIMITing?

This query works OK, but it takes too much time to execute. This query takes about 5 secs, although each table consist only less than 50 000 rows. Tried also two times faster and with more RAM server; also same times. Tables are indexed.
Is there something to do with query to speed it up or i need to consolidate tables. This means all data will be in one table.

EXPLAIN result:
[image]

Comment: `This query works OK` ... not really, because you are selecting non aggregate columns while using `GROUP BY`.  Maybe add a description about what the query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Instead of `join` you can try `inner join`.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to detect the ways of query perfomance improvement. Also you can show  `EXPLAIN` result in your question.

Comment: changing join type makes performance worse @SagarGangwal

Comment: add your index definition.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your have several indexes each for one column on the same table (`pf_prodQtySeq`).

What you should do is adding a combined index so that both parts of your `where`-clause can benefit from an index. Only one index can be used for a table so you must have both columns in the same index for a better performance.

```
alter table pf_prodQtySeq add index prLineSh_planQty (prLineSh, planQty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query executing is good. But **Using filesort** and **Using temporary** is recommended to exclude. The `WHERE` clause includes referense to `pf_prodQtySeq` table. Try forces the optimizer to join this table in the first order  to reduce MySQL extra passes number (see `STRAIGHT_JOIN` modifier for [SELECT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) or `STRAIGHT_JOIN` in [*table_references* clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)). To prevent performance reducing, monitor changes with `EXPLAIN`. See also [Optimizing SELECT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-optimization.html) for more information. Good luck!